# `logging.StreamHandler`のデフォルトのstreamは、なぜstdoutでなくstderrなのでしょうか？

Tags: python, java

## 環境

- Python 3.7.3
- logging v0.5.1.2

## 質問

Pythonのドキュメントには、`logging.StreamHandler`クラスの説明が以下の通り記載されています。

> StreamHandler クラスの新たなインスタンスを返します。 stream が指定された場合、インスタンスはログ出力先として指定されたストリームを使います; そうでない場合、 sys.stderr が使われます。

https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.StreamHandler

なぜデフォルトのstreamがstdoutでなくstderrなのでしょうか？
ログ情報は「エラー」ではないので、stdoutの方が自然のように思います。

## 疑問に思った経緯

私はもともと、Pythonより前にJavaを使っていました。
JavaのLogbackの`ConsoleAppender`では、デフォルトのstreamは`System.out`です。

> ConsoleAppenderは名前のとおり、ロギングイベントをコンソールに出力します。正確に言うと、System.outあるいはSystem.errに出力します。デフォルトではSystem.outが使われます。

https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders_ja.html#ConsoleAppender

デフォルトがstdoutであることが一般的だと思っていたので、Pythonのloggingのデフォルトストリームがstderrであることに、疑問を持ちました。

Comment: stderr の場合は出力データがバッファリングされませんので(unbuffered)、ユーザが明示的に `flush()` を行う必要がない事も関係しているかもしれません(リンク先でも言及されています「`flush()` 呼び出しを明示的に行う必要があるかもしれません」)。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@774RRさんの回答に補足すると、以下の記事が@yuji38kwmtさんの質問の参照とは逆に、Javaでもなぜjava.util.logging.Loggerはstderrに出力するか？となっています。
回答によると Java 1.4 からの仕様ということと、GNUの解説にも一般的な概念が書かれています。

[Why does java.util.logging.Logger print to stderr?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34156052/9014308)

> I would expect to get an output on the `stdout`, just like using `System.out.println();`.
> **But instead** it gets printed out on the `stderr`, which results in a red font on the eclipse console:
>
> I know that I can change this behavior by writing a custom `Handler`, but I wish to know why the default output appears on the `stderr` instead of `stdout`?
> A logger should use `stdout` for `fine`+`info` and use `stderr` for `severe` level.

回答
[Java Programming Java Logging Framework](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaLogging.html)

> **Dissecting the Program**
>
> - By default, the logger outputs log records of level INFO and above (i.e., INFO, WARNING and SEVERE) to standard error stream (System.err).
>   訳：デフォルトでは、ロガーはレベルINFO以上のログレコード（すなわち、INFO、WARNING、SEVERE）を標準エラーストリーム（System.err）に出力します。
>
> **Class Handler**
> Each logger can have access to one or more handlers. The Logger forwards LogRecords (on or above the logger's level) to all its registered handlers. The handler exports them to an external device. You can also assign a Level to a handler to control the outputs. The following handlers are provided:
>
> - ConsoleHandler: for writing to System.err.
> - StreamHandler: for writing to an OutputStream.
> - FileHandler: for writing to either a single log file, or a set of rotating log files.
> - SocketHandler: for writing to a TCP port.
> - MemoryHandler: for writing to memory buffers.

[JSR 47: Logging API Specification](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=47)
[Java™ Logging Overview](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/logging/overview.html)
[Package java.util.logging](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html)

---

[The GNU C Library 12.2 Standard Streams](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Standard-Streams.html)

> Variable: FILE * stderr
> The standard error stream, which is used for error messages and diagnostics issued by the program.
>
> 訳：標準エラーストリーム、プログラムによって発行されたエラーメッセージおよび**診断**に使用される。

---

おそらく、logbackというパッケージの主目的が「ログを処理すること」だから、デフォルトの出力先がstdoutになっているのでは？

[Logback Project](https://logback.qos.ch/index.html)

> Logback is intended as a successor to the popular log4j project, picking up where log4j leaves off.

Answer (score 2):

オイラ的にはログの出力先は標準エラーであることに違和感は何一つないのですが、慣れの問題なのかもしれません。標準出力はあくまで「実行結果」標準エラーは「その際に伴う診断メッセージ」つまり、ログは標準エラーに出力される、というのが商用 UNIX の世界では当たり前だと思っています。現に

- あまり使われていないのでしょうが `java.util.logging` の出力先も標準エラー
- `gcc` 等のエラーメッセージの出力先も標準エラー

なのでそういう伝統に則っただけなんだと思います。